# extract left and right channel in AS3 from stereo file, and invert one(vocal removal)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm building a website where people can upload music and remove the vocal part, with a flash applet. It's known that from a stereo file, you can invert one channel to let the vocals from two channels (almost) cancel up, for ordinary pop music that created in a studio. However, I cannot find any direct API of actionscript that extracts the left and right channel or inverts a waveform. Is it possible to reach this goal? Thanks!

Comment: Really? The most "direct API" is the Sound API which comes with a Sound.extract. Here is a page from the [Manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract()). So you want to invert? here's a [Hint](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/audition/cs/using/WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7f64.html).. So now how to setup Phase adjustment in code? here's another [Hint](http://philippseifried.com/blog/2011/10/13/dynamic-audio-in-as3-part-2-basics/) (scroll down to "Sound output!" section, last block).

Comment: In that Adobe `Sound.extract` example the line `returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());` is done **twice** to explicitly extract the Left and then Right audio channels (Left is default extracted channel if you call it only once)

Comment: And inverting a waveform is as simple as multiplying by -1.

Comment: Thanks, the problem has been solved!